# jquery submit of django form not firing

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, forms

I have the following form:

```
<div>
    <form id="edit-form" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset></fieldset>
        <button id="button-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to fire the submit myself so that I can do it via ajax.  The problem is that I never get to the submit handler.  Here is the code:

```
 $.post(url,data,function(result){
    $( ".page-added" ).append(result);
    $("#edit-form").submit(function (event){
         event.preventDefault();
     alert('submitted');
     return false;
});

 })
return false
});
```

The result contains the edit-form.

The problem is the alert is never fired and submit handler is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because `append()` behaves synchronously so that you bind that handler before `#edit-form` exist in the DOM.

You can use a different approach for this problem, that use `on()` on the static element:

```
// bind your submit handler here, assuming .page-added is the static element
$('.page-added').on('submit', '#edit-form', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('submitted');
});

// do your ajax here
$.post(url, data, function (result) {
    $(".page-added").append(result);
});
```

Hope it helps.